# Can you send additional data to the "User Support URL"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

If we define a "User Support URL" in the Facebook Developer App, is there a way to pass any data about the user to that URL?

Specifically, we'd like to be able to get at least the FBID of the user, so if we send them to a support form we can know who they are.

Something like a set of meta tags we can get replaced with user's information, like:

```
http://example.com/support?fbid=#FBID#
```

Comment: Ask them to authenticate with their Facebook account.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry, there is no way to do that, unless you develop your own stop in your app's screens to collect user feedback and support requests.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is to write your own feedback form as a part of the application.